How to Integrate LinkedIn API in Node.js for Fetching Recommendations
I am working on a Node.js project where I need to integrate the LinkedIn API to fetch recommendations for a user profile. I have reviewed the LinkedIn API documentation but am unclear on the step-by-step process for implementing this.
Here are my specific queries:

How can I set up OAuth 2.0 authentication for accessing the LinkedIn API in a Node.js environment?

Which endpoint should I use to fetch recommendations or related data, and what request/response format should I expect?

Are there any specific scopes/permissions required for accessing recommendations via the LinkedIn API?

Could you provide a basic example or guide for integrating the API with Node.js, including any relevant libraries or modules?


I would greatly appreciate a detailed explanation or a link to a step-by-step guide. Any sample code or implementation tips would also be very helpful.

we do this at lavodata dot com in case you want to try a scraping solution
